# Can not convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have data as input_data and output_data in csv files and after cleaning the data, this is how it looks

Converted dataframe into numpy

```
x=input_data.to_numpy()
y=output_data.to_numpy()
```

```
print(x[0])

array([17354, 19096.0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, list([5, 12]), list([3, 0, 0, 0]),
       list([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
       list([2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
       list([3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 6, 0, 0, 0]), 3, 7.0,
       list([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]), 600.0, 500.0, 2209.508536585366,
       1917.5761194029851], dtype=object)
```

shape of x is `(1098, 19)` and y is `(1098, 6)`.

```
print(y[0])
array([ 1.,  1., 40.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(28,input_dim=19,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(6,activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

`model.fit(x,y,batch_size=50,epochs=150)`

I am getting this error
`Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int)`

I know that converting array by `np.array(x,dtype=np.float)` should fix the problem but I have list of list in some columns.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: That `x[0]` has 19 elements, but it's a mix of integers, floats, and lists of various lengths.  There's no way you'll make a `tensor` out of that.  What is `input_data`?  A pandas dataframe.

Comment: yes, input_data is pandas dataframe and list was string separated by comma.